# Redimensionar imagem e adicionar espaço branco para tamanho exacto

Tags: wordpress

Eu preciso de saber como posso fazer com que as imagens no wordpress em vez de fazer hard-crop ou resize simples na escala da imagem, Fique a imagem do tamanho que pretendo e caso a imagem não tenha a mesma escala do resultado pretendido que o script/plugin nao destroça ou corte a imagem.

Algo como isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sei a resposta, mas começaria minha pesquisa [por aqui](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp_generate_attachment_metadata+add_image_size) e [por aqui](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=image%20crop%20is%3aanswer)

Comment: Acabo de descobrir que [a partir do WP 3.9](http://bradt.ca/blog/image-crop-position-in-wordpress/) a gente vai poder marcar a posição do crop no `add_image_size`.

Answer (score 1):

Com CSS é possível:

CSS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Exemplo pt.stackoverflow - Pergunta 10483</title>
    <style>
    .quadroImagem {
        display:inline-block; 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        text-align: center; 
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #999;        
        line-height: 196px;
    }
    .quadroImagem img {
        max-height: 200px;
        max-width: 200px;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="quadroImagem">
        <img src="minha_imagem.jpg" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Lembrando que o ao alterar o tamanho padrão (no exemplo, 200px) o valor de line-height deve ser sempre 4px menor, ou seja:

Para 400x400, *line-height: 396px;*
Para 100x100, *line-height: 96px;*

O *line-height* é usado para permitir a **centralização vertical** indicada na própria imagem com *vertical-align: middle;*

Teste e veja. Use imagens quadradas retangulares (com altura maior que largura e vice-versa).